# Overlaying one div element evenly above two others

Tags: html, css, sass

[image]

With this current implementation, the circle element moves across the page when the page is resized or in mobile view. I need to permanently fix the circle in position between the green and white div elements.

```css
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 4px solid pink;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 46%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  top: 26px;
  z-index: 999;
}

.green {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 20px;
}

.white {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="white"></div>
<div>
```

Comment: That code doesn't produce anything near your image. Please provide a complete example. You could use cloud based sandboxes for that like codepen or jsfiddle (among others)

Comment: you set `position: absolute;` on the circle. it is absolute relative to which container ? as your code stands it's just relative to the body

Comment: I've updated the example so it runs. It's relative to a parent div, not either of the sibling elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to move the circle inside the green section and align to the bottom, or use `::after`. This approach guarantees that circle always will be centered.
Here I used `::after' because empty elements aren't good, for this purpose exist pseudo-elements.

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.green {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 20px 20px 40px;
}
.green::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 4px solid pink;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, 50%, 0);
  z-index: 100;
}

.white {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  padding: 40px 20px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="green">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
  <div class="white">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution which does not use position at all. It utilizes CSS grids instead.

This answer is not a clear answer to the question, but shows an alternative

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  animation: resize 4s infinite;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 
    "top    top    top    top"    1fr 
    "top    top    top    top"    auto 
    "bottom bottom bottom bottom" auto 
    "bottom bottom bottom bottom" 1fr 
    /1fr    auto   auto   1fr;
}
.container .green {
  grid-area: top;
  background-color: green;
}
.container .white {
  grid-area: bottom;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.container .circle {
  grid-column: 2 / span 2;
  grid-row: 2 / span 2;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 5px solid pink;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

/* for demonstration purposes */

@keyframes resize {
  0%, 100% {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  25%, 75% {
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  50% {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="white"></div>
  <div class="circle">A</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi if you need to make the circle always horizontally aligned in center , no matter the screen size use 
    ***transform: translateX(-50%); 
    left: 50%.***

For vertical alignment in middle, use transform: ***translateY(-50%); and top: 50%***.

For both horizontal and vertical alignment in middle, use ***transform: translate(-50%, -50%); top: 50%; left: 50%***.

Below css for circle is given for your requirement. Hope it helps.

```css
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 4px solid pink;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: 26px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As in @Mihai comment

> you set `position: absolute;` to the circle. it is absolute relative
>   to which container? as your code stands it's just relative to the body

Setting `position:relative` to the `.container` you have the circle moving inside it.

```css
.container {position:relative}
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 4px solid pink;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%); /*this will align element to the center*/
  /*vertical-align: middle;*/ /*this doesn't help*/
  top: 17px;
  z-index: 999;
}

.green {
  width: 100%;
  /*position: relative;*/
  background-color: green;
  padding: 20px;
}

.white {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  /*position: relative;*/
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="white"></div>
<div>
```

Comment: to avoid using calc `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);`

Comment: I've tried setting the container to relative, circle to absolute, and removing positioning from green and white, but the circle still moves across the page when it is toggled between device views. Sorry if I am missing something!

Comment: are you sure you don't have any other css that is interfering with that?

Answer (score 0):

I have a different approach here, which might suit your needs.

In this answer the circle itself is a `relative` positioned container, which has no content except for an `absolute` positioned pseudo element `::after`. It therefore uses no space, but sits right between `.green` and `.white`.
The pseudo-element is then positioned in the center (`left: 50%;`) and translated by half its size (`transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`)

```css
.container {
  width: 40%;
  height: 320px;
  border: 1px solid gold;
  position: relative;
}


.circle {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}
.circle::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 4px solid pink;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.green {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
}

.white {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="green">AAAAA<br>AAA</div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="white">CCCCCCC<br></div>
<div>
```